# JavaScript distort image [Canvas]

Tags: javascript, image-processing, html5-canvas

**I HAVE THIS IMAGE:**

[image]

**AND WANT TO DRAW IT LIKE THIS:**

[image]

can i do this in javascript ?

Comment: Sure, you should be able to do that in JavaScript.

Comment: Post your code and specific details of what you have tried, and what does not work.

Comment: @Tristan i dont have any code. Thats the reason i asked. I just want to draw the first image that it look like the second  one. I dont know how to start.

Comment: Canvas only does affine transforms (natively) and only parallelograms will result -- no trapezoid like the yours is (natively) possible. Here's an example of creating non-parallelogram images by slicing them into pieces and resizing & repositioning the pieces: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25709306/crop-the-image-in-irregular-shape-and-stretch-it/25712001#25712001

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. Three ways of doing it, in css, canvas and svg. You also have a working example at the bottom.

**CSS**

```
#outer {
  perspective: 200px;
  -webkit-perspective: 200px;
}
#inner {
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px;
  width: 70%;
  height: 80%;
  background-color: #fff;
  transform: rotate(7deg) rotateX(40deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(7deg) rotateX(40deg);
}
```

**Canvas**

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width = 200;
canvas.height = 150;

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(50, 18);
ctx.lineTo(160, 30);
ctx.lineTo(180, 120);
ctx.lineTo(10, 100);
ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
ctx.fill();
```

**SVG**

```
<svg>
  <path d="M50 18 L160 30 180 120 10 100 z" fill="#fff" />
</svg>
```

And here is a working example of all 3 on **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/atvx3svo/)**.

Hope it helps. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for your answer but someone edited my question and swapped the titles. It was in the reversed order.